# Putnam trigonometric integral convergence (2000 Q4)

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, contest-math

[image]

I'm wondering about the following solution:

[image]

After making the substitution, the two integrals in the expression are now the same except their different lower limits of $-1$ and $0$. So doesn't that mean the infinite parts cancel and we're left integrating between $-1$ and $0$?

Comment: But the integral is convergent between $-1$ and $0$; we don't need to *evaluate* the integral, just show it converges. A continuous function over a bounded interval necessarily has a finite integral value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need to be careful. Let me demonstrate an example in which a naïve cancellation leads to an incorrect answer: Consider the integral

$$ I = \int_{0}^{\infty} (\cos^2(x^2-x) - \cos^2(x^2+x)) \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

You might be tempted to write it as

\begin{align*}
\color{red}{
\begin{aligned}
I
&\stackrel{?}= \int_{0}^{\infty} \cos^2(x^2-x) \, \mathrm{d}x - \int_{0}^{\infty} \cos^2(x^2+x) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&\stackrel{?}= \int_{-1}^{\infty} \cos^2(x^2+x) \, \mathrm{d}x - \int_{0}^{\infty} \cos^2(x^2+x) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&\stackrel{?}= \int_{-1}^{0} \cos^2(x^2+x) \, \mathrm{d}x.
\end{aligned}
}
\end{align*}

However, it turns out that the actual value of $I$ is

$$ I = \int_{-1}^{0} \cos^2(x^2+x) \, \mathrm{d}x - \bbox[background-color:#FFF0FD; border:1px solid skyblue; padding:5px;]{\frac{1}{2}}. $$

The presence of the "extra" term can be explained by studying the proper integral before the limit:

\begin{align*}
I
&= \lim_{B\to\infty} \int_{0}^{B} (\cos^2(x^2-x) - \cos^2(x^2+x)) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \lim_{B\to\infty} \left[ \int_{-1}^{B-1} \cos^2(x^2+x) \, \mathrm{d}x - \int_{0}^{B} \cos^2(x^2+x) \, \mathrm{d}x \right] \\
&= \lim_{B\to\infty} \left[ \int_{-1}^{0} \cos^2(x^2+x) \, \mathrm{d}x - \int_{B-1}^{B} \cos^2(x^2+x) \, \mathrm{d}x \right]
\end{align*}

Here, it can be shown that

$$ \int_{B-1}^{B} \cos^2(x^2+x) \, \mathrm{d}x
= \int_{B-1}^{B} \frac{1+\cos(2(x^2+x))}{2} \, \mathrm{d}x
\xrightarrow{B\to\infty} \frac{1}{2}. $$

(For example, we may invoke the substitution $u=x^2+x$ as in the solution and proceed. Or, we may invoke the Riemann–Lebesgue lemma.)